# Third monitor on Ubuntu not recognized (USB-C hub or HDMI switch?)

Tags: usb, display, hdmi, screen, monitor

I have a [Lenovo Ideapad 3 15ITL6](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/IdeaPad/IdeaPad_3_15ITL6/IdeaPad_3_15ITL6_Spec.pdf) and I've bought two HDMI switches to create a third monitor with no success. One of them only connect the output with one screen at the same time and the other just broadcast the same output to both monitors as if it was only one.

Now I've tried with a USB-C Hub with HDMI output and it works well with the USB-A input devices but it doesn't recognize the HDMI. I wonder if my laptop USB-C is not Alt Mode and it can't be used with a HDMI (at manual says data transfer only). Or maybe is something about some missing software or configuration.

My Graphics Card info is:

```
miguel@miguel-IdeaPad-3-15ITL6:/lib/modprobe.d$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
```

So, any solution up to this point? Anyway to make HDMI working on my [USB C Hub](https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B08SLR1JJV?noLL=1&askMessage=GENERIC_ERROR&th=1)? or to be sure that my laptop USB C input won't work with HDMI? Or any HDMI switch/hub that can create two external monitors on my display settings instead of broadcasting the same display on both?

Comment: Most laptops with integrated GPUs only support the native display +1. What does your hardware support?

Answer (score 1):

Page 2 of the manual you linked to says

> Supports up to 2 independent displays (native display and 1 external monitor via HDMI®)

So you will not be able to get 3 displays working without adding another video card.  (USB video cards do exist, but don't expect speed from them.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. So it won't work either with hdmi switch or usb c hub (I received a comment from the hub seller saying that my laptot usb c entry is not ready for hdmi). 

Could you please send me an example of that usb video cards? Will it work with the usb c entry or shall I buy a hdmi hub? In that case, which one will work properly? I don't need too much speed or quality because the third screen will be only for coding. 

Thanks!

Comment: HDMI hub isn't going to help you get more monitors working, that isn't what a USB hub is for.  Your video card doesn't support more than one HDMI output, and you can't change that with a hub.  Recommending products is off topic here. and searching amazon for "usb video" gave me >20 results.  Note that all of these will need drivers which are OS specific.  Read descriptions and reviews carefully.

Comment: Thank you! I found this one: [link](https://www.amazon.es/Adaptador-HD1080P-Convertidor-Projector-Compatible/dp/B07TC58F34/ref=d_pd_sbs_sccl_4_1/257-5728987-8983069?pd_rd_w=sc69y&content-id=amzn1.sym.71bd5875-7b22-4aa5-b52a-39d0a79d59c6&pf_rd_p=71bd5875-7b22-4aa5-b52a-39d0a79d59c6&pf_rd_r=9521QBZGDK8BVXP0B0X5&pd_rd_wg=DDFif&pd_rd_r=a1f3435f-f82b-4c8a-a175-668181abe1ba&pd_rd_i=B07TC58F34&psc=1) which specifically says that works only with Windows and not Linux. I'm trying to find one that works with Linux but that's not mentioned at any product. Any help here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might have more luck looking through the linux driver reviews and find a device with a linux driver, and then look for that device on your favorite retailer.